# Проблемы с динамическим массивом текстур/C++ SFML

Tags: c++, visual-c++, динамические-массивы, sfml

у меня проблема с загрузкой текстур в С++ SFML в динамический массив. Программа работает через несколько раз и, по-большему счёту, выдаёт одну ошибку: "C++ Game TeraCraft (CGTR).exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова".
Вот код функции, загружающей всё:

```
void load_texture() {
    texture_union_block = new texture_folder[block_max_id];
    texture_union_wall = new texture_folder[wall_max_id];

    for (int i = 0; i <= block_max_id; i++) {
        texture_union_block[i].def = 'b';
        texture_union_block[i].id = i;
        texture_union_block[i].texture.loadFromFile("storage/sprites/block and wall/" + std::to_string(texture_union_block[i].id) + texture_union_block[i].def + ".png");
        sprite_union_block.push_back(sf::Sprite(texture_union_block[i].texture));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= wall_max_id; i++) {
        texture_union_wall[i].def = 'w';
        texture_union_wall[i].id = i;
        texture_union_wall[i].texture.loadFromFile("storage/sprites/block and wall/" + std::to_string(texture_union_wall[i].id) + texture_union_wall[i].def + ".png");
        sprite_union_wall.push_back(sf::Sprite(texture_union_wall[i].texture));
    }
}
```

Это код texture_folder

```
struct texture_folder {
    sf::Texture texture;
    short id; char def;

    texture_folder() { id = 0; def = ' '; }

    texture_folder(short _id, char _def) : id(_id), def(_def) {}
};
```

block_max_id и wall_max_id рассчитываются по максимальным значениям матрицы. Проблем с кол-вом текстур нет.

Если кто-то знает, есть ли контейнеры по-лучше, чем простой динамический массив, но без реаллокации данных, которую делает std::vector?

Comment: Во-первых, из вопроса неясно, где именно вылет программы? Почему вы связываете его с реаллокацией в векторе? Во-вторых непонятно, что вы делаете - с одной стороны, создаете динамический массив переменных (вы потом их используете? нет ли тут простой утечки памяти?), с другой - часть (текстуры) храните в векторе. Зачем, если они уже есть в массивах - их же без всяких векторов можно добывать прямо оттуда?

Comment: Перед циклами добавьте такие две строки `sprite_union_block.reserve(block_max_id+1); sprite_union_wall.reserve(wall_max_id+1);. Это уберет у вектора необходимость в релокации. Также меня очень сильно смущает условие `i <= block_max_id`

Comment: Код вылетает в строчке подгрузки текстур. Строчка про реаллокацию - это про то, если бы я использовал бы векторы, но тут они не задействованы. А i <= block_max_id, потому что в матрице с картой может быть как и 0, так 100 и нужно открывать файлы именно так. А ошибку я уже решил, использовав векторы, сейчас придется ответ самому себе писать.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, я решил свою проблему через векторы, как и мне рекомендовали. Я просто заменил динамические массивы на векторы и заранее прописал reserve. Теперь код работает всегда, а не через раз.
Вот код:

```
void load_texture() {
            texture_union_block.resize(block_max_id + 1);
            texture_union_wall.resize(wall_max_id + 1);

            for (int i = 0; i <= block_max_id; i++) {
                texture_union_block.at(i).def = 'b';
                texture_union_block.at(i).id = i;
                texture_union_block.at(i).texture.loadFromFile("storage/sprites/block and wall/" + std::to_string(texture_union_block.at(i).id) + texture_union_block.at(i).def + ".png");
                sprite_union_block.push_back(sf::Sprite(texture_union_block.at(i).texture));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= wall_max_id; i++) {
                texture_union_wall.at(i).def = 'w';
                texture_union_wall.at(i).id = i;
                texture_union_wall.at(i).texture.loadFromFile("storage/sprites/block and wall/" + std::to_string(texture_union_wall.at(i).id) + texture_union_wall.at(i).def + ".png");
                sprite_union_wall.push_back(sf::Sprite(texture_union_wall.at(i).texture));
            }
        }
```